# $.ajax jquery is not showing the success function data what might be wrong in the function

Tags: jquery, handler

I am using a jquery like shown below its going to ?Handler excuting the code correctly and return is a json in form of  (for ex: [{"res":1}] ) so i wanted to check if i retrieve anything in success function so just gave an alert initially but the alert itself is not showing so what might be wrong? Can u please help thanking u in advance....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function DoneClick() {
    alert("OO");
    var checkLocation = "";
    var txtMM = document.getElementById("hdn_Tagging").value; ///Id s of textbox assigned in code behind MB--
    txtMM = txtMM.slice(0, - 1);
    var arrTxtMM = txtMM.split(",");

    for (var j = 0; j < arrTxtMM.length; j++) {
        var Loc = document.getElementById(arrTxtMM[j]).value;
        if (Loc == "") {
            checkLocation = "";
            break;
        } else {
           checkLocation += Loc + ":";
        }
    }
    if (checkLocation != "")
    {
        var url = 'Handler/newExifDetails.ashx?Id=' + txtMM + '&Location=' + checkLocation + '';
        alert(url);
        alert("yes");
         $(document).ready(function() {
            var url = 'http://localhost:4880/Handler/newExifDetails.ashx?Id=' + txtMM + '&Location=' + checkLocation + '';
                                $.ajax({
                                url : url,
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(data) {
                                alert(data);
                                alert("yeah");
                                },
                                error: function(data) { alert("error"); }
                               });
                                }); 
          });

    }
     else
     {
        alert("Please pick the locations for all objects");
    }
}
                    </script>
```

here the problem is that the Handler page is called as if i put the breakpoint in Handler page its going and executing correctly.... and the response.write there i am getting the json string as: for ex: [{"res":1}] now the sucess: in the $.ajax if i write an alert its not showing what might be wrong???

The Handler code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using ClassLib_BLL;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace QlixooWeb.handler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

    public class UserUploadsDTO
    {
        private int _res;
        public int res { get { return _res; } set { _res = value; } }
    }

    public class newExifDetails : IHttpHandler
    {
        public static readonly UserUploadsBLL oUserUploadsBll = new UserUploadsBLL();
        string[] splitQueryStr, arId, arLocation;
        public string Id1, Location1;

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
            Collection<UserUploadsDTO> collection = new Collection<UserUploadsDTO>();
            UserUploadsDTO dto;
            string RId = context.Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
            string RLocation = context.Request.QueryString["Location"].ToString();
            //string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();//Location = Bangalore%2C+Karnataka%2C+India%3AChittur%2C+Kerala%2C+India %3A  &  Id=4%2C94
            //splitQueryStr = json.Split('&');
            //Location1 = splitQueryStr[0];
            //Id1 = splitQueryStr[1];
            //string Location = RLocation.Substring(Location1.IndexOf('=', 0) + 1);
            string Location = RLocation;
            //Location = Location.Replace("%2C+", ",");
            //Location = Location.Replace("%3A", ":");
            //Location = Location.Replace("+", " ");
            Location = Location.TrimEnd(':');
            arLocation = Location.Split(':');
            string Id = RId;
            //string Id = RId.Substring(Id1.IndexOf('=', 0) + 1);
            //Id = Id.Replace("%2C", ",");
            arId = Id.Split(',');
            int res = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arId.Length; i++)
            {
                int UpId = Convert.ToInt32(arId[i]);
                Coordinate coordinate = Geocode.GetCoordinates(arLocation[i]);
                decimal latitude = coordinate.Latitude;
                decimal longitude = coordinate.Longitude;
                res = oUserUploadsBll.TaggingImages(latitude, longitude, UpId);
            }
            if (res > 0)
            {
                dto = new UserUploadsDTO();
                dto.res = res;
                collection.Add(dto);
            }
                //context.Response.Redirect("~/UserUploads.aspx");
                //context.Response.Write(res);
            else
                context.Response.Write("false");
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(collection);
            context.Response.Write(jsonString);

        }
        public interface ISpatialCoordinate
        {
            decimal Latitude { get; set; }
            decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Coordiate structure. Holds Latitude and Longitude.
        /// </summary>
        public struct Coordinate : ISpatialCoordinate
        {
            private decimal _latitude;
            private decimal _longitude;
            public Coordinate(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
            {
                _latitude = latitude;
                _longitude = longitude;
            }
            #region ISpatialCoordinate Members
            public decimal Latitude
            {
                get { return _latitude; }
                set { this._latitude = value; }
            }
            public decimal Longitude
            {
                get { return _longitude; }
                set { this._longitude = value; }
            }
            #endregion
        }
        public class Geocode
        {
            private const string _googleUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=";
            private const string _googleKey = "AIzaSyB4UgLW37a1jhxnnz5J27KPNaHIDmapSYk";
            private const string _outputType = "csv"; // Available options: csv, xml, kml, json
            private static Uri GetGeocodeUri(string address)
            {
                address = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address);
                return new Uri(String.Format("{0}{1}&output={2}&key={3}", _googleUri, address, _outputType, _googleKey));
            }
            public static Coordinate GetCoordinates(string address)
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = GetGeocodeUri(address);
                /* The first number is the status code, 
                * the second is the accuracy, 
                * the third is the latitude, 
                * the fourth one is the longitude.
                */
                string[] geocodeInfo = client.DownloadString(uri).Split(',');
                return new Coordinate(Convert.ToDecimal(geocodeInfo[2]), Convert.ToDecimal(geocodeInfo[3]));
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the aspx page i have used 2 script tags as :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this is used within the head tag... of the aspx page... from where i am calling the Handler..

Comment: Check if you see any errors in the console section??

Comment: TypeError: a[pq] is not a function its showing only so much in console... no page name or any other details.... i have not got any clue as to why this shows as i have not used any such thing in my coding....

Comment: can you paste your entire js file here.. Looks like there is some error on the page

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in your browser debuggion tool? There you can see the call go out and also see any possible error coming back from the server.

Comment: @sushanthreddy yes... i have edited the question and pasted entire js.. its a function which will be called in onlick event... of a button: I have also pasted the Handler code......

Comment: @FrançoisWahl i have not tried the network in the browser debugging tool let me check it once....

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following:

```
$.post("http://localhost:4880/Handler/newExifDetails.ashx", { "Id": txtMm },
   function(data){
      alert('test');
   }
   ,"json"
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

This is another way of writing the thing that you have written now. If this isn't working you could try FireBug and see what FireBug says.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `type:'GET'`

Because you set it as POST it will expect parameters in the data but not query string

```
var url = 'http://localhost:4880/Handler/newExifDetails.ashx;

     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: "POST",
         data : {'Id' : txtMM , 'Location' : checkLocation},
```

Or

```
var url = 'http://localhost:4880/Handler/newExifDetails.ashx?Id=' + txtMM + '&Location=' + checkLocation + '';

 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "GET",
```

Comment: You can have parameters in the querystring too even if you do a POST. And his serverside code is getting called so that's not the problem. He's not getting the code in the success callback fired, but as I stated in my answer the code per se is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted there's nothing wrong. I tried it in a fiddle and it works correctly, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zk8Nk/

You might have some other script in the page that is getting in the way, but I can't help you without seeing the whole page.

Comment: the Handler page is like this: within the process request:

Comment: yes... in fiddle no error its showing.. but the handler page code i am not able to paste here.. how do i send u entire page code?? please help....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that jQuery ajax call cannot handle the "%2c" in your strings.